# Typescript Recursive Mapped type for a tree with objects and arrays

Tags: typescript

I have a state tree with the following Typescript type:

```
type StateTree = {
  foo: {
    id: number,
    name: string,
    createdAt: Date
  },
  bar: {
    items: Array<{id: number, name: string}>
  },
  baz: {
    count: number,
    isVisible: boolean,
    children: Array<Array<number, number>>
  }
}
```

And I need to run a validation function on this tree. The return type of this tree should mirror the shape of `StateTree` but each of the final values should be error messages (strings) like below:

```
type Errors = {
  foo: {
    id: string,
    name: string,
    createdAt: string
  },
  bar: {
    items: Array<{id: string, name: string}>
  },
  baz: {
    count: string,
    isVisible: string,
    children: Array<Array<string, string>>
  }
}
```

I currently have a mapped type to try and do this because the real state tree is much larger. Below is my mapped type:

```
type ValidationErrors<T> = T extends object ? {
  [Key in keyof T]: ValidationErrors<T[Key]>
} : string
```

However, this doesn't work this the arrays. How can I update my mapped type to support arrays?

Comment: Are you sure the arrays don't work?  [Looks good to me.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20ValidationErrors%3CT%3E%20%3D%20T%20extends%20object%0D%0A%20%20%3F%20%7B%20%5BK%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20ValidationErrors%3CT%5BK%5D%3E%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%3A%20string%3B%0D%0Atype%20A%20%3D%20%7B%20arr%3A%20Array%3C%7B%20a%3A%20number%20%7D%3E%20%7D%3B%0D%0Atype%20B%20%3D%20ValidationErrors%3CA%3E%3B%0D%0Adeclare%20const%20b%3A%20B%3B%0D%0Ab.arr.find(x%20%3D%3E%20x.a.charAt(0)%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22a%22)%3B%0D%0A)

Comment: I'd expect `Date` to give you trouble (since `Date` is an object).  And you mention invalid stuff like `Array<string, string>`.  Please consider editing this into a [mcve].  Good luck.